# Proper set external pointer for allocate memory in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

How to use properly external pointers for allocating memory in constructors and deallocating in destructors in C++? Following is a code example that is not working properly. Please consider it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Foo
{
public:
   Foo() : str(nullptr)
   {
      str = new string();
   }

   ~Foo()
   {
      if (str != nullptr)
      {
         delete str;
         str = nullptr;
      }
   }

   void getString(string ** pStr)
   {
      *pStr = str;
   }

private:
   string * str;
};

int main()
{
   string * mainStr = nullptr;

   Foo().getString(&mainStr);

   if (mainStr == nullptr)
      cout << "is null";
   else
      cout << "is not null";

   return 0;
}
```

How to write above code in order to `mainStr` variable has the correct value (`nullptr` in this case)?

Comment: Are you aware that the expression `Foo().getString(&mainStr)` makes `mainStr` point to invalid memory?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? `Foo` is being destroyed and `mainStr` points to an invalid location.

Comment: Why are you dynamically allocating a `string` object?  This is not C# nor Java.

Comment: There is no method to set the value of the string in `class Foo`.

Comment: It's as if more and more, people are trying to find a problem to a solution. The solution being *don't declare a pointer to string - just declare a std::string member variable*.

Comment: @rgb - Try this 2 line main() program: `int main() { Foo f1; Foo f2=f1; }`  I've just introduced a double delete error.

Comment: This is a simplified example. The real class is not a `string`. This is just an example. I use `Foo foo; foo.getString(&mainStr);` in my code, but I want to know how to properly handle above case. In more realistic case you can use this class in block `{ Foo foo; foo.getString(&mainStr); }` and check `mainStr` value after block - when the destructor has been called. Internal pointer has been null in this case, but external not.

Comment: @rgb - Who is responsible for that pointer's lifetime?  Is it the Foo class, or some other class?  That is the question you need to ask yourself.  Then when you decide who's pointer it is, then you have answered your own question.  If no one is the owner, then consider using std::shared_ptr and stop all of the pointer gymnasitcs.

Comment: `shared_ptr ` is the best solution for my problem. Good answer is [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198055/best-way-to-use-a-c-interface)

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you will need an *instance* of an object in order to use it's non-`static` member functions.
In your case:

```
int main(void)
{
  Foo my_foo;
  std::string * p_string = nullptr;

  my_foo.getString(&p_string);

   if (mainStr == nullptr)
      cout << "is null";
   else
      cout << "is not null";

   return 0;
}
```

You will need to test `pStr` in `getString` for null, as assigning to a null pointer is undefined behavior.